# Error Launching Android Studio in Windows 8 64 bit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I am a beginner in android world.

I have downloaded

1. jdk1.8.0_25 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. android studio from https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

when i am starting studio.exe error pops up displaying:
"NO JVM Installation found. Please Install a 32-bit JDK"

In system properties -> advcance properties -> enviornment variables -> I have added a user variable
Variable : JAVA_HOME
Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

I have checked in cmd the java version is jdk1.8.0_25 and my system is 64 bit, after doing all this again the same error pop up when i open studio.exe in bin folder of android-studio.

Please help
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to androidstudio installed folder and go to bin folder there are files named `studio64.exe` and `studio.exe` run studio64.exe if you have installed java 64 version otherwise run studio.exe

if your version is java 64 then you should run studio64.exe .to easily run change your shortcut target to `studio64.exe` file.you are getting this error because android studio try to run 32bit version but you have installed java 64 version .

[image]